# Apply changes to a property after changing another property

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have unit tests for my program and I have to make them all successful

**This is one of my unit tests**

```
 double x = 5;
 double y = 10;
 double radius = 20;
 Circle target = new Circle(x, y, radius);
 Assert.AreEqual(40 * Math.PI, target.Circumference, 0.01, "Circumference is false");
 target.Radius = 0;
 Assert.AreEqual(0, target.Circumference, 0.01, "Circumference is at a radius of 0 0");
 target.Radius = -10;
 Assert.AreEqual(0, target.Circumference, 0.01, "Circumference is at a negativ radius null");
```

The first test is successful but the next isn't. My problem is how do I change Circumfernece when only the radius is changing?

**Here is my Circle class**

```
public class Circle
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Radius { get; set; }
    public double Circumference{ get;}

    public Circle(double x, double y, double radius)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        if (radius < 0)
        {
            Radius = 0;
            Circumference = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            Radius = radius;
            Circumference = radius * 2 * Math.PI;
        }
    }

    //...

}
```

Comment: Write code in `Circle` to recalculate the circumference when one of the underlying values changes.

Comment: Unless the class was meant to be immutable then your constructor is doing too much. So either make the members readonly or move the calculation logic into the calculated members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much better to move all the logic and validation from constructor to the properties.

This way your code will not be broken, if somebody assigns or changes `Radius` directly.

Try this

```
public class Circle
{
 
    private double _radius;
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Radius
    {
        get  {return _radius;}

        set
        {
            if (value <= 0) _radius = 0;
            else _radius=value;
        }
    }
    public double Circumference 
    { 
        get { return _radius * 2 * Math.PI };  
    }
    
    public Circle(double x, double y, double radius)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Radius = radius;
    }
}
```